# "Open Webstart page" de MAMP no funciona

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, apache, localhost, server

Tengo este problema.

Inicio MAMP y se inicia Apache y MySQL sin problema alguno. Pero quiero acceder a la base de datos local y debo entrar a la página de inicio desde el panel de control de MAMP.
En otras palabras, acceder a esta dirección "localhost:8888/MAMP/".

Pero no funciona la página y he reinstalado 3 veces MAMP y revisado los puertos y todo está normal. Pero esto me dice el navegador (lo probé con Chrome, Opera y Firefox):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué será que pasa? ¿Qué problema puede haber?

Muchas gracias a todos por vuestro tiempo,

Saludos

Comment: ¿Generaste certificados con openssl?

Comment: Hola. ¿Certificados con openssl?, ¿qué es eso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya está arreglado...era windows defender que me bloqueaba el acceso. Lo desactivé y ya puedo entrar.

Gracias igualmente.